# How to read bitcoin future report?

Tags: futures

The CBOE website features a [report on Bitcoin futures](http://cfe.cboe.com/cfe-products/xbt-cboe-bitcoin-futures) containing:

```
 Symbol         Last        Change       Volume
 XBT/F8         18090.00    +1290.00     1515
```

I understand:
XBT is bitcoin, F8 means Jan 2018.
But what do “last 18090” and “volume 1515” mean? Does this mean that in Jan 2018 there will be 1515 contracts bought at 18090? Or does it mean that in Jan 2018 there will be 1515 contracts sold at 18090? How can I learn the percentage of long and short contracts from the report?